# How to identify a smart contract transaction

Tags: transactions, contract-design, private-blockchain, events

Apologies if this is a bit of a noob question. But I have a bit of trouble understanding a concept.

I am designing a Smart Contract where I need to send data for the same transaction from multiple sources. The contract has only the contract address as an identifier, so how do I make sure the various attributes are combined in the same transaction?

For example, Oracle A will send data X to Contract B. For the transaction to be completed Contract B also needs data from Oracle C. How can I inform Oracle C where to send the data to if the contract address is the same for all transactions.

Do I create a transaction first and then work onwards using that initial transaction hash as a reference?

Comment: it is not very clear what you are trying to achieve. can you give a better example with real data.
from what i understand from the first part -> in the smart contract you can have another identifier (e.g. counter) and then oracles will send data to the contract and give the internal identifier as an additional argument. the data will be stored and managed by the internal Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to use the transaction hash as an identifier - it cannot be obtained in a smart contract. But you can generate some unique identifier for each "initial" transaction yourself, for example, a GUID (without separators, it just fits in bytes32).

The possible principle of interaction of Oracles with the contract is shown below.
In your example, Oracle A can send data to the contract via the **SendData** method. If during data processing it turns out that it is necessary to get additional data from Oracle C, then the **Request** event is raised indicating the target Oracle and the transaction ID transmitted by Oracle A.

Oracle C catches the event in its address, requests the data transmitted by Oracle A through the **GetTxData** method, and then sends the missing data through the same **SenData** method or through some other method using the ID of the initial transaction received from the event.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.6.4 <0.9.0;

contract Test
{
 
    mapping (bytes32 => string) tx_data ;
    
    event Request(bytes32  oracle_id, bytes32  tx_id); 

    constructor() 
    {
    }

    function GetTxData(bytes32  tx_id_) public view returns (string memory)
    {
       return(tx_data[tx_id_]) ;
    }

    function SendData(bytes32  tx_id_, string memory data_) public
    {
    
// Logic processing....

            tx_data[tx_id_]=data_ ;

              emit Request("Oracle_C", tx_id_) ;
    }

}
```